# Replace column with the count of specific character

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame that contains a column as the following:

```
1     string;string
2     string;string;string
```

I would like to iterate through the hole column and replace the values with the count of ";" +1 (number of strings) to get:

```
1        2
2        3
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html) function:

```
print (df)
                    col
1         string;string
2  string;string;string


df['col'] = df['col'].str.count(';') + 1
print (df)
   col
1    2
2    3
```

---

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.count(';').add(1)
print (df)
   col
1    2
2    3
```

Comment: Super, glad can help you. Nice day!